# Include file for all of namespace std

Tags: c++, std

Is there a file that has all of the includes for std:: or something like that? I have 20+ files all from the standard library that would be great if I could just include them all.

I thought `#include <cstddef>` would help since there was a long chain of includes in it, but it didn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need all those 20 files?

Comment: Yes. My project is massive and I do need all of those 20 files (iostream, fstream, limits, string, etc etc). Plus I'd like to include more stuff from the standard library but have been hesitant because my include list is already very long

Comment: Maybe you should split the file into multiple files then?

Comment: There are some compiler-specific tricks (e.g. the infamous `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`), but you shouldn't use them without *very* good reasons.  You'll save a few lines of includes, but will lose portability and last hope for decent compilation times.

Comment: Here you go: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header , now you can make your own.  Build  a pre-compiled header with them.

Comment: I just checked, `<bits/stdc++.h>` contains around 80 (!) headers. I don't think you want that.

Comment: @NeilButterworth why is that even relevant?

Comment: Because I suspect it is not "massive".

Comment: @jijemi: "*I do need all of those 20 files*" Really? You're using both scoped allocators *and* polymorphic allocators? You're using `std::deque` and `std::forward_list`? You're using locales, regex, and atomics? And you're doing all of this, *everywhere*, in all of your code? No, you're not. You just want to stop having to think about what headers each source file needs to include.

Comment: Im not using some of those things because they're c++14 and beyond, but for atomic, regex, maps, etc I do use them all and very frequently. Please stop going off topic :) @RichardCritten gave me a great place to go and a great place to start, if I could mark his comment as correct, I would.

Answer (score 2):

First consider if every single file of yours needs *every single* of those include files. If yes, and *only if you need every include for every one of your files*, then create a header called `headers.hpp` and list all of your includes there, and include `headers.hpp` everywhere you need it. If even one of those files does *not* need even one of those includes, then do not include your new header in that file. The extra typing will save you from unnecessarily bringing random headers into your code. On the other hand, there is (shudder) `<bits/stdc++.h>`, but that is best avoided for various reasons which can be Googled up.

Comment: To build your headers.hpp, consider starting with < bits/stdc++h >. For every line (in your headers.hpp), comment comment out one line.  Compile new eveything. If something does not compile, put the removal back in.  Repeat.  Let us know your original count, and how many were actually required. and how many were not found and you added.  I count 76 includes in g++-v5 <bits/stdc++h>

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN 38 were required, but it is technically more because some headers include each other (like threads including string and whatnot)